# Timer minutes is always 30 seconds out

Tags: vb.net

Goodday, I use the below code to start a timer . 
Label2.Text = Difference1.TotalMinutes.ToString("N0") 
But the minutes are always 30 seconds out. The label shows the time as 1 minute when only 30 seconds have elapsed and thereafter I'm always 30 seconds out.
How can I calibrate this?
Thanks 
Rob

Comment: Minutes don't have seconds.  They are whole numbers.  *You have some 'splainin' to do Lucy!*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at the definition for the [TimeSpan.TotalMinutes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timespan.totalminutes%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) property it states that it:

> Gets the value of the current TimeSpan structure expressed in whole and fractional minutes.

Therefore when you use the ToString("[N0](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k.aspx#NFormatString)") format you are telling it that you want no decimal places and since it is a numeric format it will round your value up. You should look at using the [`TimeSpan Custom Formats`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee372287.aspx) in particular in this case the [%m](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee372287.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-11) Custom Format string. It should look something like this:

```
 Label2.Text = Difference1.TotalMinutes.ToString("%m")
```

---

Code I used to test. Timer interval is set to 1000 and is enabled.

```
Public Class Form1
    Dim startTime As DateTime = DateTime.Now
    Private Sub Timer1_Tick(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick
        Label1.Text = (DateTime.Now - startTime).ToString("%m")
        Label2.Text = (DateTime.Now - startTime).TotalSeconds.ToString("N0")
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply ,  I,v tried the ("%m") and some veriation on it but can only get %m in the lable2 readout and not the time.